# Scala akka - not able to run program from jar-with-dependency builded by Maven

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, jar, akka

I'm new in scala and akka. I tried to setup simple akka remote project with client and server. I'm using Eclipse with maven scala plugin. Everything is working fine if I run this project from IDE. Client is able to connect to server. Unfortunately when I build my project to jar-with-dependency using maven-assembly-plugin I'm not able to run it from command line. I'm getting error like this:

> F:\Projects\sag-project-scala\sag-scala\target>scala sag-scala-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar server
>   com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka.loggers'
>           at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:124)
>           at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:145)
>           at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:151)
>           at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:159)
>           at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:164)
>           at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getList(SimpleConfig.java:212)
>           at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getHomogeneousUnwrappedList(SimpleConfig.java:271)
>           at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getStringList(SimpleConfig.java:329)
>           at akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings.(ActorSystem.scala:179)
>           at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.(ActorSystem.scala:504)
>           at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:141)
>           at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:118)
>           at com.sag.remote.ServerObject$.run(Server.scala:28)
>           at com.sag.remote.ServerObject$.main(Server.scala:25)
>           at com.sag.remote.ServerObject.main(Server.scala)
>           at com.sag.main.ScalaRunner.main(ScalaRunner.java:23)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:71)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:139)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:71)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:139)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.run(ObjectRunner.scala:28)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.JarRunner$.run(MainGenericRunner.scala:16)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:35)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.JarRunner$.runJar(MainGenericRunner.scala:28)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:78)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:96)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:105)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)

If I understand akka documentation, in custom *.conf files I'm overriding the default configuration and akka internally parses those files into one file. 
I'm pretty sure, that I'm missing something very small but after two days Googling I gave up. That's why I'm asking You for help.
It seems like it's not able to find proper configuration from application.conf but why from IDE everything is working fine?
Here are files which were used to build my example:

ScalaRunner.java

```
package com.sag.main;

import com.sag.remote.ClientObject;
import com.sag.remote.ServerObject;

/**
 * Runner class to simply run jar file from command line.
 * @author ddr
 *
 */
public class ScalaRunner {
    private static String SERVER_MODE = "server";
    private static String CLIENT_MODE = "client";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String mode = SERVER_MODE;
        if(args != null && args.length > 0){
            mode = args[0];
        }
        if(CLIENT_MODE.equals(mode)){
            ClientObject.main(args);
        }
        else if (SERVER_MODE.equals(mode)){
            ServerObject.main(args);
        }
    }
}
```

Client.scala

```
package com.sag.remote

import akka.actor._
import akka.actor.ActorDSL._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

class Client extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case msg: String => println("joe received " + msg + " from " + sender)
    case _ => println("Received unknown msg ")
  }
}

object ClientObject  {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = run()

  def run() = {
     println("STARTING CLIENT")
     implicit val client = ActorSystem("Client", ConfigFactory.load("client"))
     val server = client.actorFor("akka.tcp://server@127.0.0.1:6969/user/server")
     println("That 's remote server:" + server)
     server ! "Hello"
  }
}
```

Server.scala

```
package com.sag.remote

import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.Props
import com.typesafe.config.Config
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import akka.actor.Extension
import akka.actor.ExtensionIdProvider
import akka.actor.ExtensionId
import akka.actor.ExtendedActorSystem
import akka.actor.ActorSystem.Settings
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory


class Server extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case msg: String => println("joe received " + msg + " from " + sender)
    case _ => println("Received unknown msg ")
  }
}

object ServerObject { 
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = run()

  def run() = {
    val server = ActorSystem("server", ConfigFactory.load("server"))
    val serverActor = server.actorOf(Props[Server], name = "server")
    println(serverActor.path)
    println()
    println("Server ready")
  }
}
```

common.conf

```
include "application.conf"
akka{
    stdout-loglevel = "DEBUG"
    loglevel = "DEBUG"
    actor {
        provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
    }
    remote {
        enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
        netty.tcp {
            hostname = "127.0.0.1"
        }
    }
}
```

client.conf

```
include "common"

akka {
  remote.netty.tcp.port = 2552
}
```

server.conf

```
include "common"

akka {
  remote.netty.tcp.port = 6969
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sag-scala</groupId>
    <artifactId>sag-scala</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <inceptionYear>2008</inceptionYear>
    <properties>
        <scala.version>2.10.1</scala.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>akka-snapshots</id>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <url>http://repo.akka.io/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-remote_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-actor_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>specs</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <buildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalabuilder</buildcommand>
                    </buildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalanature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <classpathContainers>
                        <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                        <classpathContainer>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                    </classpathContainers>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.sag.main.ScalaRunner</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.sag.main.ScalaRunner</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

I will be grateful for any help.
Regards,
Dariusz

Answer (score 2):

Here is modified pom.xml which solved my problem. Maybe it will help someone.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sag-scala</groupId>
    <artifactId>sag-scala</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <inceptionYear>2008</inceptionYear>
    <properties>
        <scala.version>2.10.1</scala.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>akka-snapshots</id>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <url>http://repo.akka.io/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-remote_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-actor_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>specs</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <!-- plugin> <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId> <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId> 
                <executions> <execution> <goals> <goal>compile</goal> <goal>testCompile</goal> 
                </goals> </execution> </executions> <configuration> <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion> 
                <args> <arg>-target:jvm-1.5</arg> </args> </configuration> </plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <buildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalabuilder</buildcommand>
                    </buildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalanature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <classpathContainers>
                        <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                        <classpathContainer>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                    </classpathContainers>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                            <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                        </transformer>
                        <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Main-Class>com.sag.main.ScalaRunner</Main-Class>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.sag.main.ScalaRunner</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: The `scalanature` and `scalabuilder` are not in the `ch.epfl` namespace anymore. The correct ones are `org.scala-ide.sdt.core.scalanature` and `org.scala-ide.sdt.core.scalabuilder`